# Discord JS self nickname command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

hello guys iam trying to make self role and nickname change command but its not working i dont know where is the problem i earn the role but name not changing can someone tell me what is wrong on my code

```js
client.on('message', (message,member )=> {
  
  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '*Test') {
    
     if(!message.channel.guild) return;
  message.member.addRole(message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "Test"));
     let member = message.member; //message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    
     let nick = "[PRO] "
//  message.guild.member(r=>r.setNickname(nick + r.user.username));
            member.setNickname(nick + member.user.username);

 }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

> To set Discord nickname. You can use `message.member.setNickname("new member")` .
> as example : 
> if you want to create `#setnick [nickname]` and `[nickname]` is your args.
> and you can use this example with `role` for member

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);
  var argresult = message.content.split(` `).slice(1).join(' ');

  if(message.channel.type === "dm" || message.author.bot) return;

  if(message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('#setnick')) {

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission('MANAGE_NICKNAMES')) return message.reply('I dont have Permission to do this action.!');

    try {
      if(!args[0]) {
        message.member.setNickname(message.author.username)
      } else {
        message.member.setNickname(argresult, "Member wants to change nickname")
      }
    } catch(error) {
      return console.error('[ SET_NICKNAME ] Error')
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: its not working i want anyone can use the command get a role and his name change assign role is fine but changing nickname not working :(